# Visual Studio Code Extension Development: How can I display code inside my extension view?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a visual studio code extension. In my extension view, I need the ability to show code in an editor view from the local disk. If this is not possible then I would like the ability to open local code in a side panel along side my extension view.

Is this possible because when I browse their documentation there's no mention of displaying local code from extension view.

Comment: do you mean syntax highlighting and such

Comment: have you thought of a PeekWindow, I don't know if there is an Extension API to open one

Comment: Not very clear what you want to implement. You'd better post some drawings to illustrate your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for this workspace API:

```
workspace.openTextDocument(fileName).then((document) => {
    window.showTextDocument(document, 0, false));
}
```